# Postgres timestamp index performance

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering, when dealing with large tables (> 100 million rows)

1. Does Postgres handle work well with indexing timestamps
   (e.g: `2018-10-09T12:41:20.276846Z`)?
2. Will it improve performance if I truncate the date to the seconds if I don't care about that much precision when selecting?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact value match, or for a range of values? Can you give some examples of the queries you will be using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At StackOverflow, we are helping developers to get stronger. However, we won't never let company get rid of them by requesting free jobs on this forum. So in order to distinct yourself from these sharks, show us some effort, pieces of code, some bugs, or other... And then we will help you! Please take the tour and read "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes on timestamps work very well in PostgreSQL, because timestamps have a total ordering.

No matter what precision your timestamp value has, it will always occupy 4 bytes, so the precision has no influence on the index size or performance.

You have to make sure that your index can be used with the condition in your queries. For that, the condition must be of the form

```
<indexed expression> <operator> <constant>
```

where `<constant>` need not really be a constant, but have the same value for the duration of the index scan.

`<operator>` can be `=`, `<`, `>`, `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: More info on date/time storage requirements: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Comment: a common rewrite I find myself doing is using `ts < now() - '30 days'` instead of `ts + interval '30 days' < now()`